# How do I send an object to a server via a MIDlet?

Tags: java, server, client-server, java-me

I have a server that recieves a serialized object, handles it, and then returns output. I would like to send an object via a MIDlet, but J2ME has no ObjectOutputStream class. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Change the server to accept a format that's a bit more portable? ObjectStreams aren't that great for exchanging information.

Comment: Well, I need to send multiple variables at once, so I use a serialized object and send it to my server.

Comment: Well you don't really think that Object streams are required to send multiple pieces of data at the same time, do you? Look at JSON, you can send as much data as you want and it doesn't use Java's built-in serialization.

Comment: Json is an easy to build structured format (with support for multiple attributes). You can implement the toString method of your classes to return a String in that format and send it to the server.

Comment: So which JSON framework does J2ME support?

Comment: There appear to be some JSON parsers for J2ME on GitHub but I cannot speak to their quality https://github.com/search?q=J2ME+JSON